# Find accuracy of words associated with an outcome [BigQuery]

Tags: google-bigquery, text-mining

I have a dataset with document ids, text associated with each document, and a decision outcome, which tells me whether a specific document was true/false to be included in my group. I want to extract the words from each document and determine the "accuracy" for each word, which would be `sum(true)/total)`.

How would I write a query in BigQuery to do this?

Table example

| doc_id | text | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | This is a description of a document. | True |
| 0982 | This is another description of a document. | False |
| 3455 | This is a third description of a document. | False |
| 5666 | This is a fourth description of a document. | True |

Example of desired result

| word | docs_count | accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 45 | 40% |
| 0982 | 150 | 20% |
| 3455 | 200 | 90% |
| 5666 | 1000 | 7% |

Comment: How to define the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Split the text in each document into words. Then, count the number of times each word appears in each document. Finally, calculate the accuracy of each word by dividing the number of times the word appears in documents with the outcome "True" by the total number of times the word appears in all documents.

```
WITH words AS (
  SELECT
    doc_id,
    SPLIT(text, ' ') AS words
  FROM `my-dataset.my-table`
),
word_counts AS (
  SELECT
    doc_id,
    words,
    COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM words
  GROUP BY
    doc_id,
    words
),
accuracy AS (
  SELECT
    doc_id,
    words,
    SUM(CASE WHEN outcome = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS true_count,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN outcome = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) AS accuracy
  FROM word_counts
  GROUP BY
    doc_id,
    words
)
SELECT
  words,
  COUNT(*) AS docs_count,
  SUM(accuracy) AS accuracy
FROM accuracy
GROUP BY
  words
ORDER BY
  accuracy DESC
```